# Why are there censored/retracted art when there is no problem

Tags: daily-lives-of-high-school-boys

In some episode shorts they retract some parts, while i can understand if they infringe on other ip they retract part of the title for a Dragon Quest Game however the anime is a collaborative work with Square Enix so it doesn't make sense as to why they would retract it

also, in the short where Motoharu is killing bugs they're blurred out but in the extra episode their not

so why are some stuff censored/retracted when there really isn't any reason for it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the Dragon Quest thing was just a joke, supposed to look like any other anime using a protected name or trademark the anime is not licensed to use (even if it wouldn't cause problems, like in this case).

And the bugs were blurred out to let the viewers imagine for themselves how scary or disgusting they are, only giving the basic shape, color and such. This is a commonly used scare tactic in horror games and movies (though not necessarily pixellation, but some other blurring technique).

(*converted from comment with 3 points, since no other answers have been posted*)

Comment: Yeah, the thing with blurring out things to emphasize how disgusting they are happens a lot. See, for example, [this (hilarious) bit in _FMP? Fumoffu!_](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8FTV3mnTYdY#t=5m11s).

Comment: @senshin not available in my country.

Comment: Oh, that's a shame. It's basically the same idea as the blurred-out bugs thing in Nichibros, though - a character is shown receiving a disgusting package in the mail, and when it opens up, the insides are shown as a pixelated red mass. I just mentioned it to provide another example to support that part of your answer.